# How to jQuery delegate with out event type?

Tags: jquery, delegates

I have a facebook like feeds application. I would like to execute timeago plugin for each of the feed that gets added dynamically.

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago()
```

How do I call jQuery delegate to execute timeago() for each of the feed/new feed added dynamically?

i.e, What would be the event type on delegate method? or how to delegate with out event type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish there was a cleaner/better way to do this. I am currently having a workaround ..  
  
  `$('abbr.timeago').timeago().removeClass('timeago');`  
  
  Calling timeago() more than once doesn't work. And, it's inefficient as well. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.delegate()` works for events only. If your plugin has a custom event (which is possible) you can delegate to that. If not, you can try extending it yourself to have such an event.

EDIT: I misunderstood your question. You can indeed fire a custom event, and delegate to that:
See the last example seen on http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

try http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('abbr.timeago').live('load', function(){
    $(this).timeago();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't think you can delegate it, the only thing i think you could do is call the plugin each time a feed is added. Just put the call

```
 $("abbr.timeago").timeago()
```

after the feed is added to the DOM